# need help with javascript hint with php

Tags: php

i am using javascript field hint. problem occurred when I try to put code php translation into the hint itself.

```
<?php $interest= '<span class="hint">Eg: Cooking or Singing or Dancing<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>';?>
```

if i try to put

```
 <?php    
$interest = '<span class="hint">__("Eg: Cooking or Singing or Dancing")<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>';?>
```

the field hint at page will be displayed like this "**__("Eg: Cooking or Singing or Dancing")**"

if i try to put

```
$interest = '<span class="hint">__('Eg: Cooking or Singing or Dancing')<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>';?>
```

or

```
$interest = '<span class="hint">' __('Eg: Cooking or Singing or Dancing')'<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>';
```

error will be displayed:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\estandard\app\views\companies\company.ctp on line 7"
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: we need more of your code to help you. Show us the "echo" or "print" statements that display that code. Or if it is more complex, you might need to explain what you are using so we can assist

Comment: <?php echo $this->Form->input('user.interest', array('label' => false,  'size'=>40,'after' => $interest)); ?>                                      this is the way calling the hint at field .

Comment: there is error in your string quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $interest = '<span class="hint">'.__('Eg: Cooking or Singing or Dancing').'</span>';
```

That is if you want the value of interest to the be localized version of the string 'Eg: Cooking or Singing or Dancing'.

Comment: so how to include the  <span class="hint">

Answer (score 1):

The error for the last example is caused by missing your concatenation symbol. This should work:

```
$interest = '<span class="hint">'.__('Eg: Cooking or Singing or Dancing').'<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>';
```

Comment: the hint won't be displayed in the hint box(next to field). it appears at the top of the page.